# Can't use setStrokeColor method for material button Android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I'm using Material outlined button in Android Studio (material version is 1.4.0).
I wanted to change outline color when button is pressed. so,

```
binding.activeButton.setOnClickListener{

  binding.activeButton.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
}
```

However, I can't use `setStrokeColor` method.
It says "Unresolved reference: setStrokeColor"

[image]

I still can use `app:strokeColor="@color/white"` in the XML file, but I can't use `setStrokeColor` method in an activity file.
What would be the reason ? Is it because of material design version?

Comment: These are some errors because of koltin version, Try to update kotlin version.
Also sometimes these errors are there but project runs. You can  try it.
Also in kotlin we don't really need to use getter/setter methods.
I checked your code, it requires colorStateList.
** binding.activeButton.strokeColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(),R.color.colorPrimary)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
       binding.activeButton.setStrokeColorResource(R.color.back_color_green_btn)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it also becomes "Unresolved reference".

Comment: put Your xml code here

Comment: ` <Button
        android:id="@+id/activeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/active"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/doneButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        />`

Comment: Oh. You should use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` instead of `Button`.